# Catching all exceptions on a site the best way

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I'm trying to figure out a way to trap all exceptions on a site and store them and well the problem is i don't want to go and try catch everything.

I already figured out the resolve to a custom error page and I'm doing that, but i would like as a administrator to know when a user encountered an error, and what error. And i know there must be a way to globally get all exceptions and store them.

I have been looking for a solution or at least something pointing in the right way for days, but all I'm finding is clumsy ways of doing it.

So my question is. Is there a one stop shop kind of thing for this? Can i catch the exception and do the storing procedure in one place without adding something to every class in my solution? In that case where do i run my storing procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Global.asax file to your asp.net project and handle application error:

```
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        string errorMessage = "Application Exception: " + ex.Message;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            errorMessage += Environment.NewLine + "Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
        if (Context != null && Context.Request != null)
        {
            errorMessage += Environment.NewLine + "Absolute Url: " + Context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        }
        Services.LoggerManager.Log(
           Services.LoggerManager.eLogContext.Application,
           Services.LoggerManager.eLogType.Error,
           Context, errorMessage);
    }
```

And here is LoggerManager part:

```
public static class LoggerManager
{

    public enum eLogType
    {
        Information = 0,
        Warning = 1,
        Error = 2
    }

    public enum eLogContext
    {
        Application = 0,
        Session = 1
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Method for logging custom message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logContext"></param>
    /// <param name="logType"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    public static void Log(eLogContext logContext, eLogType logType, HttpContext context, string message)
    {
        switch (logContext)
        {
            case eLogContext.Application:
                //TODO: log application type event...
                break;
            case eLogContext.Session:
                //TODO: log session type event...
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("eLogContext '" + logContext.ToString() + "' is not implemented!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If i want one for warnings could i just add Application_Warning(object sender, EventArgs e) to the global.asax?

Comment: Nope. This event is not supported by Global.asax. However you can handle exception inside specific asp.net page and then call LoggerManager.Log(
               Services.LoggerManager.eLogContext.Application,
               Services.LoggerManager.eLogType.Warning,
               Context, warningMessage);

Comment: I would like to one thing that do I have to use throw in my code every where where I have used **try** and **catch**

Comment: In general you should avoid throwing exceptions, they are resources costly. If possible just log the "exception" and show it to user if required. Of course if you will throw a new exception Application_Error will handle the logging. Then it's a good practise to use error page. More about error pages can be found here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Answer (score 1):

In Global.asax, use this event

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Here's a link with more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at ELMAH http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

It's very popular and is available from nuget also.  It is designed to catch and manage all errors very easily. I strongly recommend it if you don't want to manage the errors yourself.